# Is the principal character mod 1 considered primitive?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-character

I am under the impression that the principal Dirichlet character $\chi_0\bmod{q}$ is primitive if and only if $q=1$.  However, I read in Davenport's *multiplicative number theory* that the principal character is "left unclassified in terms of primitivity".  So my question is as follows: *is the principal Dirichlet character $\chi_0\bmod{1}$ considered primitive?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it should be, just as $1$ is a primitive first root of unity. Do you have a compelling reason *not* to call that character primitive? It sure isn't imprimitive.  Would we decide not to call a trivial Dirichlet character a Dirichlet character at all because it doesn't have some properties common to nontrivial Dirichlet characters?

Using this convention means some theorems about primitive Dirichlet characters in a book that doesn't use that convention may need to be stated for the "nontrivial primitive characters" rather than just for the "primitive characters".  For example, the $L$-function of a nontrivial primitive character is analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$.

Comment: I think Davenport's motivation is that positive integers are classified into 1, primes, and composites, so Dirichlet characters are classified into principal, primitive, and other non-primitive characters.

Comment: @TravorLZH Nontrivial Dirichlet characters in general are not products of primitive characters, so that motivation seems strange. The analogy with primitive and nonprimitive roots of unity is more compelling and it would be quite weird to say $1$ is not a primitive $n$-th root of unity for any n when it sure looks like one for $n = 1$.